# In Skyrim, how do you revive a NPC who was in your party?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I took Benor with me to do the Statue of Meridia mission. during the fight, he was impaled by some ice sharp magic thing. I couldn't believe it he was dead!

I completed the rest of the mission and I got out of there. Is there anyway to bring him back to life and to my current location? I gave him bunch of stuff.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

When your follower "dies", they [enter a pre-death state](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/35523/3389) that generally allows them to come back to full health immediately after battle. However, if they continue to take more damage after entering that state, they will die permanently.

If there's a chance your follower is still alive but nowhere to be seen (for example, if they entered the pre-death state and you ran off, thinking they were *dead* dead), fast traveling to a location should cause the follower to appear back at your side.

If fast traveling still doesn't produce your follower, they're almost certainly fully dead. You can confirm this by trying to pick up another follower: if they agree to come with you, the other follower has ceased to be. Sorry about that.

The only thing you can do at this point—if you're not keen on loading up an earlier save or using console commands—is to find where your follower died and loot their corpse.

If you are amenable to using the console, generally you still need to find where your follower died to ressurrect them: when you do, open the console, target their corpse, and type:

```
resurrect 1
```

and press <kbd>enter</kbd>.

However, you can get around even this restriction by selecting the follower by using the `prid` command anywhere:

```
prid <RefId>
```

Where `<RefId>` is the ID corresponding to the follower, found by using the Creation Kit or by looking up the follower on [UESP](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers). Once the follower's selected, use the `resurrect` command mentioned above.

Comment: `player.moveTo [RefID]` moves your character to the NPC with RefId. It's useful if you can't find a particular NPC.

`player.placeAtMe [BaseID]` places an NPC near your location. Useful for missing followers.

To search for the BaseIDs/RefIDs of certain NPCs, refer to this site: http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Followers . Their BaseIDs/RefIDs should be on their respective character pages.

Comment: It should be noted that using the console will disable achievements.

Comment: @Krazer there's actually lots of discussion about this but it's believed that it won't actually disable them as many people have received achievements after using the console.

Comment: well I got benor back. but all the armor and weapon i gave him are gone.

Comment: @Krazer [UESP](http://uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console), on player.placeatme: "player.placeatme 000fea9b - Using this code will instantly summon an instance of an object or npc at your position. The example, in particular, summons a dragon. Not recommended for named NPCs. This code uses the Object (base) ID and not specific reference ID as it is creating a new instance of that object/actor in the world; using it with named NPCs can result in duplicates unless the original was somehow removed." Use 'prid <RefID>' and 'moveto player' instead. More info here: uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Console

Comment: Thanks this saved my marriage! In-game of cause. Had a dead party member, and nothing ruins a good wedding like a dead body.