# How can I identify which follower is mine via the console?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc

I was playing Skyrim and I had a follower in my service when, suddenly, he had disappeared into the thin air and now I can't find him anywhere. He has not left my service, so I can't recruit new followers.

The worst thing is that I do not know who my follower was. How can I use the console to find which follower is mine? Is it possible to list the IDs of all the followers so I can try to find him by trial and error?

Answer (score 3):

You can try these steps to recover your follower:

1. Try the command `set playerfollowercount <0 or 1>` This command is helpful if you have lost a follower or are bugged. `0` clears followers and allows you to recruit again.
2. Once you run this command please try fast travelling to a couple of places. That should give your follower enough time to go back to where they usually are found.
3. Try and recruit your follower where you found them initially. (NOTE: This might not work with Illia). More details here on [Illia](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Illia)
4. If your follower has died please try [this answer by Mark Trapp](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/39970/15184)
5. [Here is a comprehensive list](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Followers) of where your followers can be found or where to get them once they leave your service.

Answer (score 0):

I would try resting in a place for a couple of days. This happened to me before, and each time they showed up after a few hours.

Comment: Fast travelling to somewhere will often 'respawn' your follower also. You can fast-travel to where you currently are too, which is handy if they go for a wander.

Comment: That too, but that sometimes wouldn't work for me. Maybe it depends on the distance travelled. But resting a day works every time.

Comment: True indeed, as travelling a long way will indeed pass more than a day of ingame time.