# Can followers be killed?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Do companions die?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/35521/do-companions-die)

There's two things that have really been keeping me from using followers, based on my experience battling alongside NPCs in other games:

1. NPCs tend to rush in ahead of you to start fights you don't want started yet.
2. ## 1 tends to get NPCs killed.

If #2 is not an issue, I'm a lot more likely to forgive #1 and give it a shot.  So, what's the situation here?